# Nested frames in tkinter

Tags: list, for-loop, tkinter, nested, frames

Good Day,

Using tkinter, Python 3.5
I am attempting to create nested frames using for loops and lists to generate the frame names.
This works for the first level of frames within a frame, however the next level fails.

For example, this code works:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

frameLevel1List = ['Frame1', 'Frame2', 'Frame3', 'Frame4']
frameLevel2List = ['FrameA', 'FrameB', 'FrameC', 'FrameD']

class myUI:
    def __init__(self):
        #create main window & frames
        self.main_window = Tk()
        self.main_window.title("frame2 UI V001 ")
        self.main_window.configure(background='gray')
        w=750
        h=500
        x=100
        y=100
        self.main_window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
        self.userlabel = Label(self.main_window, bg='gray', fg='white', text = "user Label")
        self.userlabel.pack(side="top")
        self.levellabel = Label(self.main_window, bg='gray', fg='white', text = "level Label")
        self.levellabel.pack(side="top")

        #create bottom frame
        bottomFrame = Frame(self.main_window, bg='white', height=500, width=800)
        bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        #create frames from first list
        for frame in frameLevel1List:
            self.frame=Frame(bottomFrame, width=800, height = 100, bg = 'green',  highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness="1")
            self.frame.pack(side="top")
            self.framelabel = Label(self.frame, bg='blue', fg='white', text = frame)
            self.framelabel.place(x=10, y=10)


        mainloop()

UI=myUI()
```

However, when I add a second for loop to add the second list of frames within each of the first frames, I get an error.  The following code fails

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

frameLevel1List = ['Frame1', 'Frame2', 'Frame3', 'Frame4']
frameLevel2List = ['FrameA', 'FrameB', 'FrameC', 'FrameD']

class myUI:
    def __init__(self):
        #create main window & frames
        self.main_window = Tk()
        self.main_window.title("frame2 UI V001 ")
        self.main_window.configure(background='gray')
        w=750
        h=500
        x=100
        y=100
        self.main_window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
        self.userlabel = Label(self.main_window, bg='gray', fg='white', text = "user Label")
        self.userlabel.pack(side="top")
        self.levellabel = Label(self.main_window, bg='gray', fg='white', text = "level Label")
        self.levellabel.pack(side="top")

        #create bottom frame
        bottomFrame = Frame(self.main_window, bg='white', height=500, width=800)
        bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        #create frames from first list
        for frame in frameLevel1List:
            self.frame=Frame(bottomFrame, width=800, height = 100, bg = 'green',  highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness="1")
            self.frame.pack(side="top")
            self.framelabel = Label(self.frame, bg='blue', fg='white', text = frame)
            self.framelabel.place(x=10, y=10)

            #create frames from second list
            for frame2 in frameLevel2List:
                self.frame2=Frame(frame, width=800, height = 50, bg = 'yellow')
                self.frame2.pack(side="top")
                self.frame2label = Label(self.frame2, bg='blue', fg='white', text = frame2)
                self.frame2label.place(x=10, y=10)

        mainloop()

UI=myUI()
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nicholas Boughen\Desktop\py\rubrics\nestedFramesTest.py", line 43, in <module>
    UI=myUI()
  File "C:\Users\Nicholas Boughen\Desktop\py\rubrics\nestedFramesTest.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.frame2=Frame(frame, width=800, height = 50, bg = 'yellow')
  File "C:\Users\Nicholas Boughen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2584, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Users\Nicholas Boughen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2132, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\Nicholas Boughen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2110, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Anything that could help me understand what I have done wrong and create nested frames with for loops would be most appreciated.

Perhaps there's a completely different way of procedurally creating nested frames that would be better?  What I'm trying to do is to generate the frame names from a list and change the interface as the list changes.  So if more or fewer items are in the list, there will be more or fewer frames in the interface.  The list will be edited from a different interface.

lor

Comment: What is the full error message?  And what is `self.course` supposed to be?  Note that `self.frame`, `self.frame2`, etc. are pointless as instance attributes - they will be overwritten multiple times by your loops, and will end up holding only the most recent widget.  They might as well be local variables.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error.

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited to include the error and fixed the errant "course".  I am new to coding and this is my first question on stack overflow, I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

After many more hours of researching other people who had similar issues, and @jasonharper comment, I have discovered that I need to save(append) the frame ID into a list as it is created, to ensure each widget remains unique.

Here is the code that does what I want it to do:

```
from tkinter import *
import functools

class practice:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.frame_list = []


        for w in range(5):
            frame = Frame(root, width=800, height = 100, bg = 'green',  highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness="1")
            frame.pack(side="top")
            self.frame_list.append(frame)

            for w in range(5):
                frame = Frame(root, width=400, height = 50, bg = 'blue',  highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness="1")
                frame.pack(side="top")
                self.frame_list.append(frame)

                for w in range(5):
                    frame = Frame(root, width=200, height = 25, bg = 'yellow',  highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness="1")
                    frame.pack(side="top")
                    self.frame_list.append(frame)


        print('button list is', self.frame_list)



root = Tk()
root.title("frame2 UI V001 ")
root.configure(background='gray')
w=750
h=500
x=100
y=100
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
```

Thank you, I will attempt to post questions with greater clarity in future.

lor